# Saving file to subdomain

Tags: php, subdomain

**Background**

We have an [intranet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) where users can request business cards. This generates the business card and sends it as an SVG to our Marketing Manager who then sends it off to the printers. This whole process works perfectly.

**Problem**

I need to create a VCard with this script and save it to our website. This is to enable contacts to download this VCard using a link that will be embedded in a QR Code on the business card (the QR Code cant contain the VCard as it's to much info). I have already created the VCard and it works like it's supposed to.

Our website is hosted under www.example.com and our intranet is under intra.example.com. It's on the same VPS.

**Question**

Is there any way that I can save the VCard file to the www. server with the script running in the intra. subdomain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

They are running on the same computer, so they have access to the same file systems and databases.

You just need to store the data somewhere accessible from the other site.

Comment: Turned out it was a spelling mistake in my directory. This is very easy after all but thanks for the answer. It showed me that I am, in fact, not stupid. Just blind.